# variable height footer on sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a sidebar where there are menus that contains submenus so it doesnt have an exact height and other menu at the bottom also doesnt have an exact height so it contains rows could be 1 or 16 if there is a few rows that menu must have a bottom fixed but if there are more rows it doesnt .help me please ! ive tried with function that get the height of the footer but there are maaany height and doesnt seems good .

[this is the sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsFHg.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you've tried and what part isn't working.

Comment: hi , i erased the code to be honest ive  just improvised  putting conditions of  specific sizes to  the div but was a mess ... it doesnt work when i toogled the dropdown menu the menu-bottom must stay fixed just when there are few rows like the image i linked in the question but if there are more  rows it doent have to be static ...